# Is the danger of uniqid() that it creates identical IDs triggered at the same microsecond, or that subsequent microtimes result in collisions?

Tags: php

The issue of the same ID being generated if I were to call uniqid() multiple times isn't really an issue. But it's not clear to me whether there is a risk of ID collision at a later point in time? I mean, technically even proper cryptographic hashes have a chance of collision, but am I right in thinking that
uniqid is particularly susceptible?

Answer (score 2):

The result is based on the time in microseconds. As long as you call it at different microseconds, the results should be different.

But if the clock is reset back to the same time as a previous call, you would get the same result. This is the value of the `$more_entropy` parameter. If you add this parameter, it will add a random string at the end. The chance of the clock being reset to the same time and the RNG producing the same random string is miniscule. It's also unusual for server clocks to jump backwards; unless the time is very far off from correct, time corrections are usually done by changing the rate of clock increments, so it's monotonic and approaches the correct time.

Strings generated at the same microsecond on different hosts, without `$more_entropy = true`, will be the same. This is the benefit of the `$prefix` parameter; you can use something host-specific there to avoid collisions between servers. This is only needed if the ID needs to be globally unique, rather than just unique within the server.

If you use the `$prefix` and `$more_entropy` parameters, you should not really have to worry about collisions.

Answer (score 0):

No. Well, assuming your system clock isn't reseting to the same date and time every night, you shouldn't have collisions from subsequent calls. Mostly because the generated value is largely based on the unixtime with microseconds.

You run a greater risk of collision in a scenario where you have a pool of front end web servers using the same code. It's conceivable that a call made at the same exact moment could result in the same value being generated on two machines.

Use the `more_entropy` option and optionally concatenate something that identifies the server onto the unique ID to ensure it is unique.

Answer (score -1):

Since it’s based on time, there shouldn’t be future collision. As future entails a change in time.